# C++: digits vs bits?

Tags: c++, boost, standards, bit, digits

I am trying to understand the difference of vocabulary used in the C++ language between digits and bits as in :

```
CHAR_BIT;
std::numeric_limits<char>::digits;
```

Is there a conceptual difference? Maybe for weird architectures?
If so, what would be called the result of the `operator[]` of `std::bitset`. Does it give access to a bit or to a digit?

And the current documentation of boost does not help: [cppint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/cpp_int_ref.html) provides a code with `Digits` but the documentation mention `Bits` (this is obviously a problem with the documentation, but I don't know whether the text or the code is more recent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this `std::numeric_limits::digits` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits):

> The value of std::numeric_limits::digits is the number of digits in base-radix that can be represented by the type T without change. For integer types, this is the number of bits not counting the sign bit.

And later it states that for `char` the result is `CHAR_BIT - std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed`.

And from the [C numeric limits reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits):

> `CHAR_BIT`    number of bits in byte

So for a normal modern computer, where `char` is eight bits, then `CHAR_BITS` is equal to `8` and the `digits` function will return either `7` or `8` depending on if `char` is signed or not.

I agree that the using the word "digits" is is kind of confusing when getting the number of bits in an integer type, but it makes much more sense for floating point types:

> For floating-point types, this is the number of digits in the mantissa.

---

And [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is a set of *bits*, so the indexing operator will give you the selected *bit* in the set.

Comment: Your example for signed/unsigned char clarified the thing for me: a signed char is 7 digits but 8 bits.